# How to optimize JSON data?

Tags: json, optimization, redundancy

For the sake of optimization i do not want to include the name in the JSON data i.e.

```js
{
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
}
```

to

```js
{
"employees":[
    {"John", "Doe"},
    {"Anna", "Smith"},
    {"Peter", "Jones"}
]
}
```

This is because i already know the name and i can easily use the values correspondingly. In the above example i as a programmer know first field is firstname and the second one lastname. So why are we including the name? Why can't we include values only? It would be very optimized in terms of memory.

Please suggest how to design and use the JSON without name in application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using dictionaries, which by definition store values by key, you can just use simple arrays, and access the data based on the index instead of the key.

Like this:

```
{
    "employees":[
        ["John", "Doe"],
        ["Anna", "Smith"],
        ["Peter", "Jones"]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
"employees":[
    {"John", "Doe"},
    {"Anna", "Smith"},
    {"Peter", "Jones"}
]
}
```

It is not a valid JSON [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) you can validate. You can use [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).